# Automated Gnome Installation: How to disable the Configuration-Wizard?

Tags: linux, centos, gnome

**Is there a way to avoid the GNOME 2 first-time configuration wizard?** Maybe by changing a file?

After installing my Desktop Environment by

```
yum -y groupinstall "X Window System" 
yum -y groupinstall "Desktop" 
yum -y groupinstall "General Purpose Desktop"
```

When starting my Desktop Environment for the first time I get the following screen:

[image: Screenshot]

Gnome-Version: 2.28, OS: Centos 6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

After the installation of the desktop environment execute the following:

```
# Deactivate Service firstboot
sudo chkconfig firstboot off
# Create file that simulates that firstboot service already run
sudo echo RUN_FIRSTBOOT=no > /etc/sysconfig/firstboot
```

This deactivates the firstboot service. Addionally create a file that indicates that the first boot service was already running.